# ID Check Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am implementing docusign ID Check throught API and successfully integrated into the project but I have a question, can we increase the number of questions in ID check process throught API because by default docusign provides users with just 3 questions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using the ID Check (Knowledge based authentication), it is not possible to provide the questions and answers for a given recipient. The information source is currently LexisNexis, and they provide the questions. You seed the ID Check with recipient information, and you can configure a couple of different levels of complexity to the questions, but they control the experience.

More details on the official documentation here : https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-user-guide-signing-id-check-authentication